# Unknown error when processing PHP form?

Tags: php, forms

Below is the code for a simple form with input/output. For some reason, only question one seems to be working and questions two and three simply echo back "Something is wrong." I coded all three questions the exact same way throughout so I'm not really sure why question two and three aren't processing correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML form:

```
      <form action="processor.php" method="post">
      <h4>Question # 1</h4>
      <p>What grade are you in?</p>
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="grade" value="1"> Freshmen</label>
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="grade" value="2"> Sophomore</label>
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="grade" value="3"> Junior</label>
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="grade" value="4"> Senior</label>

      <h4>Question # 2</h4>
      <p>What is your current GPA?</p>
      <select>
      <option name="gpa" value="4">3.5 or above</option>
      <option name="gpa" value="3">3.0-3.4</option>
      <option name="gpa" value="2">2.5-2.9</option>
      <option name="gpa" value="1">2.0-2.4</option>
      <option>Lower</option>
      </select>

      <h4>Question # 3</h4>
      <p>Where do you excel the most academically?</p>
      <select multiple="multiple">
      <option name="school" value ="1">Mathematics</option>
      <option name="school" value ="2">Literature</option>
      <option name="school" value ="3">History</option>
      <option name="school" value ="4">Humanities</option>
      <option name="school" value ="5">Science</option>
      </select>
      <div class="button">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" input type="submit" name="submit" href="processor.php">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Here is the processor:

```
  <?php

 function Grades () {
 $grade = $_POST['grade'];
 if ($grade =="1") {
 echo "You're a freshmen";
 } elseif ($grade == "2") {
echo "You're a sophomore";
 } elseif ($grade == "3") {
echo "You're a junior.";
 } elseif ($grade == "4") {
echo "You're a senior.";
 } else {
echo "Something is wrong.";
 }

 }

 function Gpa () {
 $gpa = $_POST['gpa'];
 if ($gpa =="1") {
    echo "You strongly need to up your GPA.";
} elseif ($gpa == "2") {
    echo "You're an average student.";
} elseif ($gpa == "3") {
    echo "You're an above average student.";
} elseif ($gpa == "4") {
    echo "You're an excellent sudent.";
} else {
    echo "Something is wrong.";
}

}

function School () {
 $school = $_POST['school'];
 if ($school =="1") {
    echo "You're into Math";
 } elseif ($school == "2") {
    echo "You're into Lit";
 } elseif ($school == "3") {
    echo "You're into history.";
 } elseif ($school == "4") {
   echo "You're into humanities.";
 } elseif ($school == "5") {
   echo "You're into science.";
 } else {
   echo "Something is wrong.";
 }

 }

 include('viewpage.php');

?>
```

And the view page:

```
     <h4>Question # 1</h4>
     <p><?php Grades($grade); ?></p>
     <h4>Question # 2</h4>
     <p><?php Gpa($gpa); ?></p>
      <h4>Question # 3</h4>
     <p><?php School($school); ?></p>
```

Comment: Unknown error... What is the message? how isn't it working to how you expect

Comment: it doesn't return any error message. For question 1 it spits back whatever I select on the form but for question two it spits back "something is wrong" where it should say something like you're studying humanities or your gpa sucks, as noted above.

Comment: Seems like you have no name set for "Lower". Try `<option name="gpa" value="0">Lower</option>`, then edit the rest of your code to accomodate the change/addition.

Comment: Why not try some debugging? Print out the value of `$gpa` along with the error message.

Comment: there is no error message but I'll try printing the variable.

Comment: i fixed the error mentioned by Fred but question 2 and 3 are still echoing "something is wrong"

Comment: @buttonitup See Yogesh's answer below which is another thing that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 <select name="gpa">
 <option value="4">3.5 or above</option>
```

To access `$_POST['gpa']` `<select>` tag should have `name` property as `gpa` not `<option>` tag

For `$_POST['School']`

```
<select  name="school" multiple="multiple">
<option value ="1">Mathematics</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

also i think some think wrong in view page code. Grades,Gpa,School function are not have variable. but you call these function like this, 
`<?php Grades($grade); ?>
<?php Gpa($gpa); ?>
<?php Gpa($School); ?>`
 
replace these code like below
`<?php Grades(); ?>
<?php Gpa(); ?>
<?php Gpa(); ?>`

and also you will get error if user not select options in question1 n question 2. you must add code to check that..